# WPF app + PHP, fastest way of communicate data

Tags: php, .net, wpf

Hello may be you can help me. I'm wondering about the fastest way to send and receive information between a WPF App (client) and a PHP (web hosting server).

Is TCP with sockets the way to go? or it'll have problems with the firewalls and IT related stuff?

Do you recommend me to go for a REST PHP version?

Webservices?

I would like to connect this two technologies in the fastest way without enviroument restriction (like the firewall or IT stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Really, anything that uses HTTP on standard ports would probably work. At least, as well as it would be able to behind a firewall.

So that leaves your options open. Here's a few ideas:

- Use JSON and normal HTTP requests.
- Use XML and normal HTTP requests. (this may be a bit easier for the .NET side)
- Use SOAP.
- Use XML-RPC.

Pick one. The first two are easier to implement on the PHP side, and relatively easy to implement on the .NET side. SOAP is fairly easy to connect with .NET; I'm not sure about PHP SOAP libraries. XML-RPC is somewhat hard on the .NET side, and I'm not sure about the PHP side either.